# Problema al agregar contenido a mi repositorio en Git

Tags: git, github, git-bash

tengo un pequeño problema cuando intente subir un proyecto a Github con Git. Yo subi mi proyecto y todo bien, pero hay un detalle y que cuando estaba pusheando el proyecto con

```
Git push -u origin master
```

Resulta que mi rama principal se llamaba main y no master. Y lo que hizo fue crearme una nueva rama con el nombre de master. Pero, cuando intento ver que ramas tengo desde git bash me aparece solamente master. Aunque en mi repositorio de git sigue apareciendo main.

Ahí esta el repositorio de GitHub se ve que tiene dos ramas

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y en está se ve como Git solo me detecta la rama master. Por lo cual, no puedo hacer cambios en main, ni eliminarla. No hay tanto problema en funcionamiento, pero me parece feo, que cuando entras a Github aparezca primero la rama main vacia.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguna idea de que puede estar sucediendo

Answer (score 0):

Puedes configurar github para que la rama master pase a ser la principal:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Puedes (y no es excluyente con lo anterior) borrar la rama main en github, si es que no tiene nada que quieras preservar.

Puedes, en tu local, cambiarte a la rama main, convirtiéndola en una copia de master

```
 git checkout -b main
```

Y luego pushear forzando que se pise el contenido del remoto

```
git push main origin/main -f
```

El flag -f probablemente será necesario porque el commit raíz de ambas ramas es distinto, y por tanto aunque estuvieran ambas vacías, no se puede hacer merge entre ramas con distinto root, por diseño.

Una última alternativa, que es pésima en realidad, es configurar tu rama master para que trackee la rama main del remoto. Uno tarde o temprano se confunde y pierde tiempo y/o código.